# Extract specific substring which not preceding with specified substring

Tags: regex, vba, vbscript, catia

I have a question that is relatively simple but brought me to the wall.
I want to have a regex do following task in VBA (VBScript_RegExp_5.5).

Given a string like this:

```
"PrivateFactoryAsclsFactoryPrivateFactoryAsclsFactory"
```

I want to remove only the occurrences of `"Factory"` that are not preceded by `"cls"`. For this particular case, if all matches are correctly replaced with `"_"`, the result will look like this:

```
"Private_AsclsFactoryPrivate_AsclsFactory"
```

Of course, a simple exclusion trick like `"clsFactory|(Factory)"` does not works in VBA, nor do look-behinds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can do a negative lookbehind with a bit of a hack using the VBScript Regex library. The following pattern matches any two or less characters *or* any three characters that aren't `"cls"` (using a negative lookahead), followed by `"Factory"`.

```
Const strText As String = "PrivateFactoryAsclsFactoryPrivateFactoryAsclsFactory"

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "(^.{0,2}|(?!cls).{3})Factory"
    .Global = True
    Debug.Print .Replace(strText, "$1_")
End With
```

Output:

```
Private_AsclsFactoryPrivate_AsclsFactory
```

Comment: solution works nice and is slightly more complex than expected, time to study again :) thank you for your fast answer! ( you just have a small typo, it ends with end with not with end if)

Comment: Oops, typo fixed. Thanks.